# How to delete a NuGet library

Tags: nuget, nuget-cli

I've accidentally created a library in NuGet and want to delete it (so far, nobody has downloaded it). I've installed the NuGet CLI, and tried the following command:

```
nuget delete mynugetlibrary 1.0 -source nuget.org
```

When I do this, it asks me for a username and password; however, I log-in to NuGet using my Microsoft username and password (which don't seem to be accepted by the NuGet CLI). How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

[nuget.org does not support permanent deletion of packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/policies/deleting-packages).

But when you look at your package page while logged in, you should see a "contact support" link and on the form you can select "The package was not intended to be published publicly on nuget.org". This is something you can only do on the website, you can't do it through nuget.exe.